# How do I create one MySQL index for 2 SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

```
SELECT * FROM messages_messages WHERE (from_user_id=? AND to_user_id=?) OR (from_user_id=? AND to_user_id=?) ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I have another query, which is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages_messages WHERE from_user_id=? AND to_user_id=? AND read_at IS NULL
```

I want to index both of these queries, but I don't want to create 2 separate indexes.

Right now, I'm using 2 indexes:

```
[from_user_id, to_user_id, created_at]
[from_user_id, to_user_id, read_at]
```

I was wondering if I could do this with one index instead of 2?
These are the only 2 queries I have for this table.

Comment: Are you that space limited that you cant do it with two?  What happens when you create  the index `[from_user_id, to_user_id, created_at, read_at]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need both indexes for these two queries if you want to optimize fully.

Once you reach the column used for either sorting or range comparison (`IS [NOT] NULL` counts as a range predicate for this purpose), you don't get any benefit from putting more columns in the index. In other words, your index can have:

1. Some columns that are used in equality predicates
2. *One* column that is used either in a range predicate, or to avoid a filesort -- but not both.
3. Extra columns used in neither searching nor sorting, but only for the sake of a covering index.

So you cannot make a four-column index that serves both queries.

The only way you can reduce this to one index, as @JohnBollinger says, is to make an index that optimizes for one query, and uses a subset of the index for the second query. But that won't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) explain fairly completely how MySQL uses indices.  In particular, its optimizer can use any left prefix of a multi-column index.  Therefore, you could drop either of your two existing indices, and the other would be eligible for use in both queries, though it would be more selective / useful for one than for the other.

In principle, it could be more beneficial to keep your first index, provided that the `created_at` column was indexed in descending order.  In practice, MySQL allows you to specify index column order, but in fact implements only ascending order.  Therefore, having `created_at` in your index probably doesn't help very much.

Comment: How do I index it in descending order? It's possible to specify?

Comment: In a DBMS that supported it, you would add the `DESC` keyword after the appropriate column name in your index definition.  MySQL is not such a DBMS.  As I explained in my answer, MySQL accepts that syntax but does not honor it.  **With MySQL**, therefore, dropping the index with `created_at` probably would have little impact on your query performance.